# When is coal considered to be oxidized?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

What amount of oxidization is required to refer to some coal as oxidized coal, and how long does it take for coal to become oxidized in temperatures of roughly 25-40°C?

I have found a research paper from 1940 that I don't have access to [here.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ie50362a021) But other than that, I have had no luck. Does anyone have any ideas or references I can refer to.

Comment: It is a pretty specialized, industrial terminology I am not familiar with, so take this comment with caution, but after superficial reading of the article it seems: 1) not the carbon, but the other organic content of coal is oxidized and this oxidation is highly dependent both on the coal quality and external factors (temperature, moisture etc). 2)  there is no "oxidized coal", but more like a level of oxidation, without strict boundaries. The terminology mostly refer to the loss of heating value during storage.   ,